# How create bat file for copy Zero-width non-joiner

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, copy-paste, clipboard

I need a character that is necessary for for Arabic:
Zero-width non-joiner

So how can i create a BAT file or (something like this) that will do this:
1. click on file
2. automatically open the CMD (just like a flash!)
3. copy "Zero-width non-joiner" to my clipboard
4. automatically close the CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Your character has an 'Alt' code of 200C, so you can type into your target window

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm

Comment: It tells me to type this: Alt +200C. I like alt codes. But how to type Alt+200C. (What is the The Last "C"). Alt+200 (without "C") is: ╚ . and Alt+200C (With "C"): nothing happen.